# use search text for finding mongodb desired subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

I have a model called Shop which has an attribute called Products which is an array of objects. now in the products I have a property called title. User send me a searchText and a shopId. based on this two i want to do a search text query on the shop that has the id equal to shopId and find the products of this shop which has the searchText that user send me. for this I created an index for products.title

`ShopSchema.index({ 'products.title': 'text' });`

I've written this query

```
await this.shopModel.aggregate([
         {
            $match: {
               _id: new Types.ObjectId(shopId),
            },
         },
         {
            $unwind: '$products',
         },
         {
            $replaceRoot: {
               newRoot: '$products',
            },
         },
         {
            $match: {
               $text: { $search: 'something' },
            },
         },
      ]);
```

but it throw an error saying

`$match with $text is only allowed as the first pipeline stage`

If i move the search query to the top It doesn't filter products and will return any shop that has a product that has the searchText in its title

Comment: can you add findOne() object of your data.

Comment: does replacing $match with this helps? ```{
    $match: {
      'title': { $regex: '.*something.*', $options: 'i' },
    },
  },```

Comment: I could use regex but my preference is to use the full text search in mongo